# I need to split every 3 li's and append them to a div

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a generic list

```
<ul>
  <li>list item1</li>
  <li>list item2</li>
  <li>list item3</li>
  <li>list item4</li>
  <li>list item5</li>
  <li>list item6</li>
</ul>
```

But what I want to do is

```
<div class="list">
  <ul>
    <li>list item1</li>
    <li>list item2</li>
    <li>list item3</li>

  </ul>
</div>

<div class="list">
  <ul>
    <li>list item4</li>
    <li>list item5</li>
    <li>list item6</li>

 </ul>
```

I have used this script but its only showing 2 `li` element in 1 `div` my reqirement is to make 3 `li` in one `div`

```
    $('ul > li:nth-child(2n-1)').each(function() {
    $(this).next().add(this).wrapAll('<div class="list"><ul></ul></div>');
}).eq(0).closest('div').unwrap();
```

Comment: hi Farhad can u please help me to solve this problem. What mistake i am doing can you please let me known

Comment: Are the lists dynamically generated?  Like for example, with PHP or Java on the backend?

Comment: 2n-1 will cycle every 2, you should use 3n-1...

Comment: hi salketer i have allready used 3n-1 its not working

Comment: here is my fiddler
https://jsfiddle.net/sensex00007/mwpd3vgm/

Comment: Hi brett its not that type of things to wrap every 3 din in a div.If u can give me the correction in my  code it would be helpful for me

Comment: @ASHU your fiddle doesn't work because it does not have jQuery...

Comment: @salketer
https://jsfiddle.net/sensex00007/mwpd3vgm/1/
now i added jquery in my fiddler

Answer (score 3):

```js
$('ul > li:nth-child(3n-2)').each(function() {
  $(this).next().add($(this).next().next()).add(this).wrapAll('<div class="list"><ul></ul></div>');
}).eq(0).closest('div').unwrap();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li>list item1</li>
  <li>list item2</li>
  <li>list item3</li>
  <li>list item4</li>
  <li>list item5</li>
  <li>list item6</li>
</ul>
```

The key was to use 3n-2 to target the right elements (1st, 4th and so on), then add to set the 2 next sibblings, and wrap.

You were very close!

Comment: Actually i want 3 li in one div using this its not working

Comment: it is, run the code snippet to have the proof...

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/sensex00007/

u can chek it here...can u please modified here

Comment: no I will not. I provided you with the solution to your question already. You should better explain what you want or at least say what's not working.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/sensex00007/mwpd3vgm/1/

can u chek it here now i added jquery in my fiddler

Comment: hi Salker i want item1,item2,item3 inone div or in one box here is my jsfiddle  can u please check it and update me what mistake i m doing 
https://jsfiddle.net/sensex00007/mwpd3vgm/1/

Comment: just read your script, read the script in my answer and see what's wrong... There is no point in having someone else rewrite your script everytime you make a mistake.... It's better to learn by correcting them yourself. I have told you what needed to be done in plain text too. Please, pretty please, take time to read and re-read my answer and do some work yourself. Or else you'll never learn and always will need to ask the same questions here over and over!

Comment: HI Salker I did as  your told me but still not able to get the result what i am aspected still my 3 item are not coming in one div , my item3 is coming out of the box ..can you please tell me what mistake I am still doing.
https://jsfiddle.net/sensex00007/mwpd3vgm/2/

Comment: HI Salker , thanks now its working .... here is my updated jsfiddle

https://jsfiddle.net/sensex00007/mwpd3vgm/13/